# Is there any way to constrain a Kotlin type parameter to an interface type?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'd like to be able to implement two interfaces with one object, so something like

```kotlin
fun thing(c1: CharSequence, c2: Iterable<Int>) = object : CharSequence by c1, Iterable<Int> by c2
```

but in a generic way -

```kotlin
fun <C1, C2> thing(c1: C1, c2: C2) = object : C1 by c1, C2 by c2
```

The compiler complains `C1 Only classes and interfaces may serve as supertypes` - is there any way that I can placate it?

Motivation:

I'm playing with context receivers, and would like to be able to write a function to construct a context from two implementations, rather than the current:

```kotlin
    val contexts = object :
        Clock by Clock(Instant::now),
        AnalyticsContext by AnalyticsContext(loggingAnalytics) {}
    val routes =
        with(contexts) {
            routesFor(
                stockFile = file,
            )
        }
```

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit more with maybe a better example?

Comment: What would you prefer to see? I've given my question and my motivation and what the compiler says.

Comment: What you added helps, but I *thought* I had an idea but it didn't work. So I have to admit I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to limit generic type params to just interface types, unfortunately. But if your ultimate goal is just to specify several contexts, you probably don't need to create a third object out of the 2. You could just use 2 `with` to provide both in scope:

```kotlin
val routes = with(Clock(Instant::now)) {
    with(AnalyticsContext(loggingAnalytics)) {
        routesFor(stockFile = file)
    }
}
```

If you want a more convenient way to deal with 2 `with` calls, you could also extract that into your own function (e.g. `withBoth`) to call it this way:

```kotlin
val x = withBoth(Clock(Instant::now), AnalyticsContext(loggingAnalytics)) {
     routesFor(stockFile = file)
}
```

Note that, to implement `withBoth`, I needed to use one context receiver and one regular receiver on the `block` function type:

```kotlin
fun <C1, C2, R> withBoth(c1: C1, c2: C2, block: context(C1) C2.() -> R): R = block(c1, c2)
```

This allows calling `withBoth` both with a function reference and with a lambda. The proper expected way (with 2 context receivers) somehow only allowed `withBoth` to be called with a function reference as `block` argument, using a lambda failed with the compile error `No required context receiver found`. This might be similar to [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-51243/False-positive-error-No-required-context-receiver-inside-contextual-lambda), which will apparently be fixed in 1.7.20

Comment: So `withAllThree` isn't possible at the moment?

Comment: I've accepted this answer, although the pedant in me says that it hasn't answered the original question ;-)

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor I believe it might actually be possible to implement withAllThree, but maybe in 1.7.20-Beta. And to the pedant in you, technically the answer to the question is "no", so the first sentence is the answer :D

Comment: Dammit, out-pedanted

Comment: Damn... Golf clap.